# Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a react-native appliction.

I have a forEach iteration, in which I used await to wait for the result, but I keep getting error : "Unexpected reserved word 'await' ".  I don't understand why?

```
const removeData = async () => {
    try {
      dataArray.forEach((data) => {
        // What is wrong with my 'await' usage here??? It is a async API
        const deletedData = await API.graphql({ query: deleteData, variables: { input: data } });
       
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error deleting data:', err)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the function it's in **isn't** an `async` function, it's a non-`async` function (the callback to `forEach`). `await` has to be *directly* inside an `async` function,¹ not inside a synchronous function inside an `async` function.

If you want to use `await` there, use `for-of`:

```
const removeData = async () => {
    try {
        // Does the deletions in series (one after the other)
        for (const data of dataArray) {
            const deletedData = await API.graphql({ query: deleteData, variables: { input: data } });
            // ...presumably use `deletedData` here...
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error deleting data:", err);
    }
};
```

That way, the `await` is in the `async` function.

The above does the deletions in *series* (one after the other), which seemed to me to be what you wanted. But just in case, you can do the operations in parallel using `map` and `Promise.all`:

```
const removeData = async () => {
    try {
        // Does the deletions in parallel (all running together)
        const deletedDataArray = await Promise.all(dataArray.map(
            data => API.graphql({ query: deleteData, variables: { input: data } })
        ));
        // ...presumably use `deletedDataArray` here...
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error deleting data:", err);
    }
};
```

---

¹ Or at the top level of a module, in environments that support top-level `await`.